# Связка Symfony и socket.io: Авторизация

Tags: symfony, socket.io

Собственно, сабж. Имеется веб-сервер с Symfony, имеется клиент socket.io и socket.io сервер. Нужно провести авторизацию пользователя из Symfony в socket.io, как это можно сделать? Скажем, например, для чата? Чтобы только авторизованные могли писать и видеть в чат.

Answer (score 0):

При рукопожатии socket.io проверять наличие и валидировать токен пришедший в запросе. Валидацию можно проводить при помощи http запроса на Symfony-сервер.